# TypeError: DataFrame.any() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: encryption, lets-encrypt, encryption-symmetric

## Trying to encrypt a sentence with a key encrypt but i have an issue with the use of df.any()

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=encryptionkey)


df['Character'] = df['Character'].astype(str)
df['Byte'] = df['Byte'].astype(str)


def split(message):
    return [char for char in message]


message = "It is a beautiful day to code something new. In fact, a day like any other, with new projects and ideas. Maybe also new challenges and nerve-rackings bugs. Time will tell."


message_split = split(message)


print(message_split)


def code_message():
    coded_message = ""


    for i in range(len(message_split)):
        j = message_split[i]
        try:
            coded_char = encryptionkey.loc[encryptionkey['Character'] == j, 'Byte'].iloc[0]
            print(type(coded_char))


        # To handle if character is not in our decryption list
        except:
            print('unrecognized character')
            coded_char = '@@@'


        coded_message = coded_message + coded_char
    return coded_message


coded_message = code_message()


print('Your coded message:', code_message(), '\n')


def decode_message(message):
    new_word = ''
    decoded_message = []


    for i in range(0, len(message), 2):
        j = message[i:i + 2]
        index_nb = df[df.eq(j).any(1)]


        df2 = index_nb['Character'].tolist()


        s = [str(x) for x in df2]


        decoded_message = decoded_message + s


    new_word = ''.join(decoded_message)


    return new_word


coded_message_str = str(coded_message)
print('Your decoded message:', decode_message(coded_message_str))
```

> ---
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> Cell In[79], line 1
> 1 print('Your decoded message:', decode_message(coded_message_str))
>
> Cell In[77], line 9, in decode_message(message)
> 7 for i in range(0, len(message), 2):
> 8     j = message[i:i + 2]
> 9     index_nb = df[df.eq(j).any(1)]
> 11     df2 = index_nb['Character'].tolist()
> 13     s = [str(x) for x in df2]
>
> TypeError: DataFrame.any() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given